# Unit mongod.service entered failed state. When try to start mongod in Amazon Linux

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-linux

I have an Amazon Linux server and I have installed mongod using below steps and took refer from AWS mongod docs

Configure the package management system (yum).¶
Create a /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.2.repo file so that you can install MongoDB directly using yum:

```
[mongodb-org-4.2]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/4.2/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc
```

Install the MongoDB packages.
To install the latest stable version of MongoDB, issue the following command:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

Start MongoDB.
You can start the mongod process by issuing the following command:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

If you receive an error similar to the following when starting mongod:

Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
Run the following command first:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then run the start command above again.

```
**mongod.conf**

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: false  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.


#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:
```

**When try to start mongod facing below Error**

-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.

Aug 01 06:56:08 ip-000-o-o-000.us-east-0.compute.internal mongod[31765]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.

Aug 01 06:56:08 ip-000-o-o-000.us-east-0.compute.internal mongod[31765]: forked process: 31768
Aug 01 06:56:08 ip-000-o-o-000.us-east-0.compute.internal mongod[31765]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14

Aug 01 06:56:08 ip-000-o-o-000.us-east-0.compute.internal mongod[31765]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.

Aug 01 06:56:08 ip-000-o-o-000.us-east-0.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14

Aug 01 06:56:08 ip-000-o-o-000.us-east-0.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.

-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed

-- Defined-By: systems

### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

### -- Unit mongod.service has failed.

-- The result is failed.

Aug 01 06:56:08 ip-000-o-o-000.us-east-0.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.

Aug 01 06:56:08 ip-000-o-o-000.us-east-0.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.

Aug 01 06:56:08 ip-000-o-o-000.us-east-0.compute.internal sudo[31753]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

**Log file**
getting below logs

```
    {"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.932+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.932+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExtern$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.933+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 spe$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.934+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.934+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is requir$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.942+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.943+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.943+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.943+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.943+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":4932,"port":27017,"$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.943+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.10"$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.943+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Amazon Linu$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.943+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"co$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.943+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.943+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdo$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activit$
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-02T05:04:47.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the directory **/data/db** exists.

To create the directory:

```
sudo mkdir -o /data/db
sudo chown mongod:mongod /data/db
```

Verify the correct file ownership (mongod:mongod)

```
ls -ld /data/db
```

Comment: thank you @ John Hanley for your suggestion but I still have the same issue

Comment: @rayn - edit your question with more details. Include the mongod.conf file and the service configuration file.

Comment: Added mongo config file in my question, please have a look @john hanley

Comment: @rayn Change **fork** to false. Then start MongoDB manually: `mongodb -f /path/to/mongod.conf` Add the command and errors to your question.

Comment: changed fork : false and executed 'mongodb -f /etc/mongod.conf.' there is no output

Comment: [root@ip-000-0-0-0 /]# mongodb -f /etc/mongod.conf
bash: mongodb: command not found

Comment: Sorry, the server binary is **mongod**.

Comment: Since you have enabled logging, the error(s) should be in **/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log**

Comment: Henley updated my question with log file

Comment: Your log file is truncated. Please copy and paste everything.

Comment: Updated logs in quetion, please have a look @john hanley

Comment: Your log is truncated on the right-hand side as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, try this:

$ sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /data/db

Next, try this:
As you may know, the directories inside /var/run/ get deleted upon reboot. If it's okay to create the /var/run/mongodb directory when the mongod service starts, you can add the following content to the mongod.service file:

$ sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -m 0755 -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
```